# Run a Python 2.7 Script on a Webpage

Tags: python, django, cgi, wsgi

I have a couple of Python 2.7 scripts I need to have them run from a webpage. I've never done this before, although I'm comfortable coding in Python and well versed in Linux, Apache, Nginx.

I see many different frameworks like the old CGI, WSGI, Django, etc.
I need some recommendations for a framework that would require not much changes on my Python code for it to run on a webpage.

It seems CGI would be fairly easy for me, but since there are many newer frameworks, I need some advices.

Thanks!

Comment: By "run on a webpage", do you mean on the front-end, or on the backend?

Comment: The Python script would run on the backend. The page I need to create is basically a tool for people to get some specific information. I don't need to build a website, just to create a webpage (tool) to run my Python script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is probably the most straightforward Python web framework to use. It touts itself as a *micro framework*, and is very, very fast to get up and running with.

If you have a relatively straightforward set of requirements, I'd highly recommend giving it a look over. You can find the "hello" world example on the project's homepage here: http://flask.pocoo.org/

Depending on your project's requirements (does it need to be highly available/resilient?), you may even be able to get by using Flask's built-in development webserver along with a process control system such as [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/). I wouldn't recommend this for heavy or production workloads, but for something running out of production this set up would work just fine for you.

Comment: The page I need to create is basically a tool for people to get some specific information. I don't need to build a website, just to create a webpage (tool) to run my Python script. Would Flask be a good framework for this purpose?

Comment: Absolutely. Just retrofit your Python script with the few lines required for a Flask application (on the Flask project homepage), and you're good to go. You can probably have the whole thing done in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for client side browser frameworks in Python, there are [skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/) and [brython](http://www.brython.info/).

When I was looking for a similar framework, I decided to learn leave python for a javascript framework (particularly AngularJS and Node JS) for a client side language. I personally felt that the size of community and learning resources available in those two areas were more robust, and provided greater opportunity to master the framework.